# What is an \if?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I'm reading [TeX by Topic](http://www.eijkhout.net/tbt/), but in little chunks (rather than from first page to last) and just read the stuff on conditionals.  I want to be sure that I understand what's going on when TeX starts skipping stuff.  What I've gleaned so far is that in, say, `\iffalse ... \fi` then:

1. TeX doesn't do expansions.
2. TeX keeps track of `\if...`s to ensure that the `\fi` really matches the `\iffalse`.

It's that last bit that I'm wanting to make sure that I get straight in my head.  To make it a precise question:

What exactly is an `\if...`?

One reason for my worry is that I have some pseudo-ifs in my code, where a command *starts* `\if...` but isn't actually an `\if`.  On the other hand, what if I had a command that *didn't* start with the three characters `\if` but happened to be `\let` to an `\if`?  So, for example, which of the following count as an `\if` when the **macro** (not the definition of it) is used between `\iffalse ... \fi`:

1. `\let\ifabc=\ifx` (so, to be clear, what happens in `\iffalse ... \ifabc ... \fi`, does the `\ifabc` count as an `\if`?
2. `\def\ifabc{\ifx}`
3. `\edef\ifabc{\ifx}`
4. `\let\ifabc=\SomePreviouslyDefinedCommandThatIsntAnIf`
5. `\let\abc=\ifx`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When TeX is skipping tokens in a *false* path of a conditional it looks at every token without expanding it and modifies an *if*-counter very similar to the brace counter. If the token is a primitive `\if...` token (e.g. `\let` to any of TeX's original conditionals like `\if`, `\ifx`, `\ifnum`, ...) the counter is increased and if it's identical to `\fi` (i.e. `\fi` or any macro let to it) the counter is decreased. The name of the macro is not important. Conditionals *inside* other macros are never seen.

To answer your questions in detail:

1. `\let\ifabc=\ifx` (so, to be clear, what happens in `\iffalse ... \ifabc ... \fi`, does the `\ifabc` count as an `\if`?

   **A:** Yes, `\ifabc` counts as an if.
2. `\def\ifabc{\ifx}`

   **A:**  No, `\ifabc` isn't a `if`. It will work in the *true* path, because it is expanded there, but not in the *false* path.
3. `\edef\ifabc{\ifx}`

   **A:** This wont work, because `\ifx` is expanded and therefore awaits its two input tokens and the final `\fi`. Even so, primitives can't be expanded to their underlying meaning, otherwise they wouldn't be primitives.
4. `\let\ifabc=\SomePreviouslyDefinedCommandThatIsntAnIf`

   **A:** As I've said above , the name doesn't matter; this is not an `if`.
5. `\let\abc=\ifx`

   **A:** The name doesn't matter; this is an `if`.

For further information about the if-switches see *The TeXBook* in "*Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros)*", page 207 ff.

Comment: Could one say that each token is tested against one of the originals using the same testing scheme as `\ifx`?  (And presumably the test isn't against the actual, say, `\if`, but against an immutable `\if`.  So if I did `\let\if=\somethingelse` then it wouldn't break the matching mechanism.)

Comment: I don't understand that last bit. The reason `\newif` inside `\if…\fi` breaks is, as far as I can tell, that `\newif` is outer, so it is not allowed in skipped text.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, IMHO it is like `\ifx`, but I think it is executed deeper in TeX. And yes, AFAIK TeX is keep the original definitions of the primitives around even when they are redefined to macros.

Comment: @Andrew, @Martin: I don't think Martin's last comment is correct, but it should be easy to test that.

Comment: @Harald: Sorry, I actually removed that part in favor of the the other text. No `\newif` isn't `\outer` in LaTeX but in TeX, don't ask me why. What I meant with this line was that defining and using a new `\if...` inside a conditional path which can be false will break, because it will then not be defined and not match its `\fi` s.

Comment: @Andrew: I am not sure I understand your question, but let me point out that TeX primitives and the control sequences usually denoting them are two different things. Try `\let\somethingelse\if \let\if\relax \show\somethingelse` for example: It says `\somethingelse` means `\if` even though `\if` doesn't mean `\if` anymore. The tests done when skipping text is against the TeX primitives – the names of commands is irrelevant. Uh, maybe that means the answer to your question is “yes”.

Comment: @Hendrik: `\let\mymacro\relax \def\relax{} \show\mymacro` gives `\mymacro=\relax.`, so TeX still remembers the original primitive `\relax`. That was what I meant.

Comment: @Martin: Oh, I had tested in TeX only. And if you mean “defining and using”, you should say that.  8-)

Comment: @Harald: Yup, you understood my question enough to answer it!  Thanks.

Comment: @Martin: This has nothing to do with primitives but with the way `\let` works. And if you leave away `\let\mymacro\relax` before `\def\relax{}`, then `\relax` is gone. (OK, `\relax` is easily reconstructed, but with `\if` you're lost then, I think.)

Comment: As a general point, when TeX shows you the meaning of a primitive (`\show = \show`, _etc_.), the second '`\show`' is an _internal_ token and not a 'normal' control sequence. That's why something like `\let\mymacro\relax \def\relax{} \show\mymacro` gives `\mymacro=\relax`: you are seeing the internal token (essentially the memory location containing the definition of, in this case, the `\relax` primitive).

Comment: @Hendrik: With a recent engine, there is always `\(pdf)primitive` to get at the original definition.

Comment: @Joseph: Interesting! And what if I do `\def\primitive{}`? `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Then it doesn't work (there are no immutable names in TeX)

Comment: @Martin: LaTeX doesn't use `\outer` for `\newif` as it is a pain as you can't do lots of 'natural' things. (Indeed, for LaTeX3 we're not using `\outer` at all.)

Comment: To clarify things a bit: when we say "the `\if` primitive" we mean a control sequence token whose meaning is the original (IniTeX) meaning of `\if`. TeX usually tests not for a specific control sequence, but for specific meanings. (An important exception is `\par`.) As a corollary to Martin's explanations, you cannot easily define a macro that can be used with the same syntax as the conditional primitives (a popular way is `\let\then\iffalse \def\ifsomething\then{}`).