# Can I use" \iffalse ... \fi" to solve this problem?

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file)

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\hide{\iffalse}

\def\show{\hi}

\begin{document}

111111

\hide

222222

\show

333333

\hide

444444

\show

555555

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explicitly state the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  If you replace the `\show` with `\fi` I think you will get the desired results.  While you are at it, you might as well replace the `\show` with `\iffalse`.

Comment: Note that `\show` is already defined by (La)TeX and you have a typo in your code: `\hi` instead of `\fi`. Your code doesn't work, because the `\fi` is hidden inside the `\show`. When text is ignored after a `\iffalse`, macros are not expanded, so the `\fi` is never found. See also [What is an \if?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12015/2975) for more info about it. Also [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11177/2975) should be interesting for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
\let\hide\iffalse
\let\unhide\fi% rather than \show
```

to achieve your desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\hide\iffalse
\let\unhide\fi
\begin{document}
111111 \par
\hide
222222 \par
\unhide
333333 \par
\hide
444444 \par
\unhide
555555
\end{document}
```

However, the same result is possible using a more controlled approach provided by the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/comment
\begin{document}
111111 \par
\begin{comment}
222222 \par
\end{comment}
333333 \par
\begin{comment}
444444 \par
\end{comment}
555555
\end{document}
```

`comment` allows version control of comment environments.