# newcommand does not work with \fi

Tags: macros, conditionals

I tried the command `\newcommand{\fistudenti}{\fi}`  but it seems to work properly only in some cases. Here below there are two insances when it works and when it does not:

WORKS:

```
\documentclass[0pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\def\PentruStudenti{1}
\newcommand{\fistudenti}{\fi} 
\begin{document}              
\if\PentruStudenti1
show
\fistudenti
\end{document}
```

But if I put `\PentruStudenti{0}` it does not work:

```
\documentclass[0pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\def\PentruStudenti{0}
\newcommand{\fistudenti}{\fi} 
\begin{document}              
\if\PentruStudenti1
show
\fistudenti
\end{document}
```

Where do I do the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to TeX! You can make the code apparent by indenting it with 4 spaces, or by marking the code and pressing the `{}` button. Furthermore we usually don't supply a thanks in the question as that is implicit by your name tag. Enjoy your stay at TeX! :)

Comment: I guess you probably wanted to do `\let\fistudenti\fi`....

Answer (score 18):

The conditional *primitives* `\if..`, `\else` and `\fi` need to be directly visible by TeX and can not be hidden inside macros. If TeX finds a false `\if..` clause it looks at all following tokens until it finds a token equal to `\else` or `\fi` *without* expanding macros. If it finds another `\if..` conditional it increases an internal counter and will look for the `\fi` for this conditional before looking for the outer one.

If you have a macro like `\newcommand{\fistudenti}{\fi}` the `\fi` is hidden and not found. The same is true for own `\if..` macros inside a *false* clause. Both will work in a *true* clause because there macros are expanded as normal.

To make your macro work you need to use `\let\fistudenti\fi` instead, which makes `\fistudenti` a token identical to `\fi`. This is also the way used by `\newif` to define now conditionals. The `\xxxtrue` and `\xxxfalse` macros defined by it simply include `\let\ifxxx\iftrue` or `\let\ifxxx\iffalse`.

For further reading have a look at the Q&A [What is an \if?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12015/2975).

Answer (score 9):

The reason why your `\fistudenti` does not work has been explained in other answers. I'd like to add a different way to cope with your problem.

It seems that your `\PentruStudenti` is used for delimiting parts that are conditionally included in your document, depending on the meaning of this macro.

While

```
\if\PentruStudenti1
  <material for the students>
\fi
```

works, you can be better served with a different approach.

### `\newif`

Define a conditional:

```
\newif\ifstudentsversion
%\studentsversiontrue    % new conditionals start false

...


\ifstudentsversion
  <material for the students>
\else
  <optional material not for the students>
\fi
```

Then you can uncomment the `\studentsversiontrue` line for getting the same you'd get with your `\def\PentruStudenti{1}`.

### Macro with arguments

```
\newif\ifstudentsversion
%\studentsversiontrue    % new conditionals start false
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\studentsversion}{%
  \ifstudentsversion
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}

...

\studentsversion{<material for the students>}
                {<material for the teacher>}
```

Again uncommenting the `\studentsversiontrue` line will switch between printing the first rather than the second argument.

Note that this can go along with the other method. Which one to use in a particular case probably depends on the size of the material.

### Comment character

With a good editor it's not difficult to select a region and add at the beginning of the lines some characters; in this application I choose to prefix the “only students” parts with `^^A`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\showstudents}{\catcode`\^^A=9 }
\newcommand{\hidestudents}{\catcode`\^^A=14 }
\hidestudents % default

\begin{document}
\showstudents

This material is seen by everybody.

^^A This material, instead,
^^A is seen only when so
^^A decided.

And this material always shows.
\end{document}
```

If the `\showstudents` line is commented out, the `^^A` combination will be seen as a comment character exactly like `%`. If it's not commented, `^^A` will be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

The TeXBook explains this situation.

> Conditionals. When an `\if`... is expanded, TeX reads ahead as far as
>   necessary to determine whether the condition is true or false; and
>   if false, it skips ahead (keeping track of `\if`...`\fi` nesting) until
>   finding the `\else`, `\or`, or `\fi` that ends the skipped text.

So in your first example the test is true and so it expands the part. In your second example the test is false; and TeX searching a `\fi`