# Macros with \fi for showing and hiding proofs

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like to be able to globally showing and hiding proofs on a document, and be able to use macros to open and close the proof environments. Here is my current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newif\ifshowproof
\newcommand{\bp}{\ifshowproof\begin{proof}}
\newcommand{\ep}{\end{proof}}
\showprooffalse

\begin{document}
Goodbye.
\bp
Hello.
\ep\fi
Test.
\end{document}
```

As explored here: [newcommand does not work with \fi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120342/newcommand-does-not-work-with-fi), I cannot simply add `\fi` to the definition of `\ep`, however, I would like to have a "catch-all" macro so to say, that is, ideally something that would execute as `\end{proof}\fi`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: related: question 173118

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `\NewEnviron` to define a `Proof` environment that does what you want:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifshowproof
\showprooffalse

\NewEnviron{Proof}{%
    \ifshowproof%
        \begin{proof}%
            \BODY
        \end{proof}%
    \fi%
}%

\begin{document}

Goodbye.
\begin{Proof}
Hello.
\end{Proof}
Test.

\showprooftrue
Goodbye.
\begin{Proof}
Hello.
\end{Proof}
Test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've seen them before, but out of curiosity, what do the ``%`` at the end of each line for the ``Proof`` definition do?

Comment: Additionally, when I try to add ``\newcommand{\bp}{\begin{proof}}`` and ``\newcommand{\ep}{\end{proof}}``, the environment displays regardless of the setting on ``\ifshowproof``.

Comment: @AbeSchulte: Well ever since [Tex Capacity Exceeded (if remove % after use of macro)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/tex-capacity-exceeded-if-remove-after-use-of-macro) I have gotten into the habit of adding `% at the end of a line, even when it is not absolutely necessary. There are a few cases where this is a problem but I have not run into them. See [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/when-is-it-harmful-to-add-percent-character-at-end-of-lines-in-a-newcommand-or).

Comment: @AbeSchulte: I have a feeling that the `environ` package needs to see the `\end{Proof}` directly, and not a macro that means `\end{Proof}`.

Comment: In that case, do you happen to know of another solution that does allow for macros?

Comment: I don't, but others might. You could always just get your text editor to expand the text to the `\begin{Proof} ... \end{Proof}` environment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14127/discussion-between-abe-schulte-and-peter-grill)